# Strictly checking for alphanumeric in string not special characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I am having list of strings `"This is plain text" ,"[]","{}","()"`  i want to filter out all those where there is only special characters for e.g i want to exclude `"[]","{}","()"` as there isn't any number or char (A-Z ,a-z ,0-9).

```
 `
          for(short i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                if(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(list.get(i)))
                 list.remove(i);
            }`
```

But it is not working . Not removing `[] , () ,{}`

Comment: `list.removeIf(e->e.replaceAll("\\W+","").length() ==0 );` worked for me

Comment: What about contracted words, like "can't" or "don't"?  Also, hyphenated words, like "stack-overflow".  Should they be filtered?

Answer (score 1):

3 lines of code and 4 problems. Impressive :)

> `if(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(list.get(i)));`

The semi-colon **is** the instruction that is being run, i.e. nothing. And then the next line (`list.remove(i);`) is therefore always run. Just use braces, or at least, no semi-colons at the end of an `if`.

> `list.remove(i);`

This shifts all elements down by one, effectively, making you skip entries. For example, if element '0' is to be removed, you remove it, and then what used to be element 1, is now element 0. But, `i` is going to go to `1`, so, you don't look at this at all. Either copy data over to a new list, or iterate from the end (`for (int i = list.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)`).

> `short`

No. `int`. short is less efficient (I'm guessing you think it's more efficient. It is less so. Writing code casually more performant is effectively impossible so stop it. Just write code that is easy to understand. If you don't know how, make it look like every example and snippet. If you think you know better, it takes about 15 years before you might actually be likely to be right when you do).

> `if(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(list.get(i)))`

I believe you meant `if (!StringUtils...)` - you want to remove them if they are **not** alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 1-liner:

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]*"));
```

The works by removing strings that are made entirely of non-alphanumeric chars.

Comment: This is going to be the most idiomatic approach; most likely will execute faster than a `StringUtils` call, also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the strings with special characters, you should be checking if the string is *not* alphanumeric rather than if it is. Also, you need to put curly braces after your if statement rather than a semicolon:

```
 for(short i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
         if(!StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(list.get(i))) {
                 list.remove(i);
         }
 }
```

EDIT: Also, while I don't believe that @rzwitserloot's sarcasm at the beginning of their comment was warranted, they do have a good point regarding `list.remove(i)` shifting the array.

Updated code:

```
 for(short i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
         if(!StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(list.get(i))) {
                 list.remove(i);
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code isn't working is because you're trying to remove an item in a list that you're iterating over.
This will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To avoid this, use an iterator, and make sure `list` is assigned an `ArrayList`.

```java
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (!StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(iterator.next()))
        iterator.remove();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you add `i--;` to the end of your `if` clause, or use another datastructure like `Stack` or something similar.

After `List.remove()`, all your indexes will have shifted.

Comment: I think using `for(String i : list)`  should also work

Comment: Also delete semicolon in the end of if statemenet.